# Integrate aws api gateway with an internal load balancer in a different account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

I'm new to AWS. We have two AWS accounts. One where an AWS API Gateway stands, that's responsible for authenticating clients requests.
The second account has an ECS cluster within a private network.
We want to forward some requests from the API gateway in the first account to a number of ECS instances in the second account through an (internal) load balancer that it's unexposed publicly.
That way we can reuse the the authentication framework in the first account and at the same time keeping the cluster in the second account private where all intercommunication doesn't need to be authenticated.
I read about VPC peering and different kind of API Gateway integration approaches. But I'm still unsure how to apply it to this specific case.